# RECORRER DATOS FETCH

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, fetch

Quiero mostrar cada pokemon traído de la pokeapi. Al tener que hacerlo con un ID, se creó un bucle para recorrer estos ID. Para luego mostrarlos con la función createPokemonCard y obtener sus datos prediseñados y sumarlos al html... **El problema es que en vez de mostrarme a cada uno de los pokemons recorridos, cada tarjeta creada "pisa", se pone encima, de la anterior. De esta manera, una vez que el bucle finaliza en el nro. indicado, sólo muestra el pokemon respectivo al ID último.**

```
   const getPokemons = id => {
        let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`; 
        
        fetch(url)
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((pkmdata) => {
            let pokemonesGenerados = [pkmdata]; 
            pokemonesGenerados.forEach( (pokemonGenerado, index) => {
                console.log(index, pokemonGenerado); 
                createPokemonCard(pokemonGenerado); 
            });

        });
    };

    const fetchPokemons = (number) => {
        for (let i=1; i <= number; i++){
            getPokemons(i);
            // console.log(i); 
        }
    };

    fetchPokemons(12);
```

De esta forma, siempre que el bucle finaliza, en pantalla termina la tarjeta de butterfree:(

---

```
 const createPokemonCard = data => {

        const sprite = data.sprites.front_default;
        const { stats, types } = data;

        pokeImg.setAttribute('src', sprite);
        pokeNumberId.textContent = `#${data.id.toString().padStart(3, 0)}`;
        pokeName.textContent = data.name;

        pokeTypesContainer(types);
        pokeStatsContainer(stats);


    };
```

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido a SO. al parecer estas usando la funcion `insertAdjacentHTML`, pero no de la manera en que la documentación lo indica [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
de modo que deberia quedar algo como esto :

```javascript
pokeCard.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', createPokemonCard(pokemonGenerado));
```

Claro siempre y cuando tu función `createPokemonCard` devuelva un string

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias! Por más que use `insertAdjacentHTML`, puedo dar con el mismo resultado sustituyéndolo por:  `createPokemonCard(pokemonGenerado);` ya que `createPokemonCard` devuelve datos del fetch. De todas formas, el problema persiste. 
No sé por qué no muestra todos los elementos recorridos del array con la función  `createPokemonCard` y simplemente queda el último luego de hacer el recorrido.

Comment: @panchezko Agrega a tu pregunta el código de la función0 `createPokemonCard`, y como has definido `pokeCard`.

Comment: el problema es que el índice de cada elemento del array me lo devuelve en la posición 0. Por eso cada tarjeta de pokemon se pisa sobre la anterior, quedando como resultado final el último elemento del bucle...

Comment: @panchezko En ese caso tu problema puede ser en esta linea ` let pokemonesGenerados = [pkmdata];`  prueba `[...pkmdata]`

Comment: ahí modifiqué el .then con un forEach. Por consola cada elemento lo muestra... Cada elemento tiene de índice 0 (no sé por qué) y esto hace que se pisen simultáneamente las tarjetas siguiendo el bucle...

Comment: @panchezko `[pkmdata]`  te crea un array con un solo elemento por eso todos tienen index 0. prueba a llamar la funcion sin recorrer el arreglo  `createPokemonCard(pkmdata)`

Comment: sigue el mismo problema de todas formas... Comienzo a creer que el problema es en `fetchPokemons` ...